# MongoDB Failed to connect to: localhost:27017: Timed out after 1000 ms

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine, doctrine-odm

I can't connect to MongoDB server. This is what error i got :

> Failed to connect to: localhost:27017: Timed out after 1000 ms

This error happen just today, everything was working fine before I can't figured out where this error coming from.

When I start mongodb with the cmd : **net start mongodb** i got this message :

> The Mongo DB service was started successfully.

What i can do to fix this error ?

Thank you.

Comment: Make sure it's actually listening, use `netstat` for example.

Comment: Look like the port 27017 is not active. What's wrong ?

Comment: Check mongo's logfile.

Comment: On logfile i can find the real problem : ERROR: Insufficient free space for journal files. My hard disk was full. Now working fine.

Comment: Where can I find the Mongo log file? I'm using Wamp.